# C++ queue non locking

Tags: c++, c++11, libcurl, deque

I have a problem where Thread A is receiving video data from a curl callback and adding the data to an `std::deque` while Thread B is reading the data off the `std::deque` and processing it.

I lock the `std::deque` when Thread A  is adding data to it and lock it when Thread B reads data from it.

Everything is working fine but after a few minutes my curl call back eventually stops dead and receives no more video data.
I assume that Thread B takes too long to Process the data and is therefore holding onto the lock for too long, as a result the curl call back eventually stops dead.

Is there any queue that I can use in C++ where I don't have to lock it when adding and reading from it??

I can post my code if need be.

Comment: A simple way to do this would be to push pointers onto the deque. When you need to process one, take the lock only for as long as necessary to pop the pointer. Then you release the lock before processing the data. (Consider using `std::unique_ptr` so you don't have to manually manage memory.)

Comment: Or have the reader have its own `deque` and only lock for long enough to `swap()` the empty deque with the shared one. The swap will be faster than adding or removing items. Then the reader processes everything in its copy of the queue, empties it, and then locks and swaps it with the shared one again.

Answer (score 4):

Boost provides lock-free queues but they have restrictions like only being allowed to store POD types.

A common solution is for the consumer to have its own queue object, which starts empty, and gets swapped with the shared queue object when it contains work.

```
std::mutex global_queue_mutex;
std::condition_variable work_available;
std::deque<Work> global_queue;

void consumer()
{
  std::deque<Work> local;
  while (true)
  {
    // wait for work to be available and then swap it into local queue
    {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(global_queue_mutex);
      work_available.wait(lock, [&]{ return !global_queue.empty(); });
      local.swap(global_queue);
    }
    for (auto& work : local)
    {
      // do work
    }
    local.clear();
  }
}

void producer()
{
  // ...
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(global_queue_mutex);
    global_queue.push_back(std::move(work));
  }
  work_available.notify_one();
  // ...
}
```

The consumer only holds the lock long enough to check for work and do a swap, which will be very fast. The producer only holds the lock long enough to push a single item onto the queue.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid locking, you could use a bounded, lockfree queue. One can find such a thing in boost: [boost::spsc_queue](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.html)

Checking for a full queue on the producer side also makes it possible to stop the curling thread to avoid overloading.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Intel's Threading Building Blocks containers, notably [concurrent_queue](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_queue_cls.htm) and [concurrent_bounded_queue](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_bounded_queue_cls.htm).